# Making A File I/O Palindrome checker, currently returning false on everything, why?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, file-io

The problem is here:

> Write a version of a palindrome recognizer that accepts a file name from 
>   the user, reads each line, and prints the line to the screen if it is a palindrome.

My code so far:

```
def palindrome_io(file_, mode):
    stuff = "`~!@#$%^&*()_-=+[]{}\|;:,<.>/?"
    with open(file_, mode) as f:
        for line in f:
            for char in line:
                if char in stuff:
                    line.replace(char, "")
            if line.lower() == line[::-1].lower():
                print True
            else:
                print False
    palindrome_io(r'C:\Users\Brian Gunsel\Desktop\test.txt', 'r+')
```

My input file (`test.txt`):

```
Racecar
paLinDRomE
!Racecar?
Document&
```

It is returning `False` for all of them, when it should be returning `True`, `False`, `True`, `False`.

Answer (score 3):

Python strings are immutable. You need to affect the string returned by the replace method. Also, line feed character must be stripped. This should work:

```
def palindrome_io(file_, mode):
    stuff = "`~!@#$%^&*()_-=+[]{}\|;:,<.>/?"
    with open(file_, mode) as f:
        for line in f:
            for char in line:
                if char in stuff:
                    line = line.replace(char, "")
            if line.lower().strip() == line[::-1].lower().strip():
                print True
            else:
                print False
palindrome_io(r'C:\Users\Brian Gunsel\Desktop\test.txt', 'r+')
```

Comment: What does strip() with _no_ args do?

Comment: It'll remove leading and trailing \r \n \t and space characters

Comment: @pie Actually, complete list of characters strip() will remove is `["\t", "\n", "\v", "\f", "\r", " "]`. See PY_CTF_SPACE entries in _Py_ctype_table (https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Python/pyctype.c).

Answer (score 2):

So many loops! :) You don't need to loop through the string character by character; [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate) does this for you.

Try like this:

```
def palindrome_io(file_, mode):
    with open(file_, mode) as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.translate(None, "`~!@#$%^&*()_-=+[]{}\|;:,<.>/?").lower().strip()
            print str(line == line[::-1])

palindrome_io(r'C:\Users\Brian Gunsel\Desktop\test.txt', 'r+')
```

More directly, the problem is that [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) *returns* the replaced string; it doesn't replace it in-place (Python strings are immutable). You're just discarding the return value. But, nonetheless, it's not Pythonic to iterate over each character in the string in a `for` loop like that, if it can be avoided.

It also seems like there may have been some newlines/whitespace at the end of the characters, so I added a `.strip()` to our line assignment to remove any such characters (Windows `\r\n`'s perhaps).

Comment: It still returns False for all four of them, :( What could possibly be causing that?

Comment: Try now. I think it may have been the Windows `\r\n` line endings or other whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you're using replace() method in a wrong way. string.replace() method returns a altered copy of original string, as strings in python are immutable.
Example:

```
string = "123/321"
string.replace("/", "")
newstring = string.replace("/", "");
print(string) #prints 123/321
print(newstring) #prints 123321
```